# Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError) bin/rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

When I run:

```
$ bin/rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get this error:

```
gems/fog-core-2.1.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options': Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)
```

This is my `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_credentials = {
  provider:              'AWS',
  aws_access_key_id:     ENV['ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_KEY'],
  region:                'ca-central-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['AWS_STORAGE']
  config.fog_public     = false
  config.fog_attributes = { cache_control: "public, max-age=# 
  {365.days.to_i}" }
end
```

I am using:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]
```

to manage my environment variable.

Please help.

Comment: Are you setting those values 'ACCESS_KEY_ID' and 'AWS_KEY' in production env? You are using `dotenv-rails` for development and test env only.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I've already set production env on heroku

Answer (score 0):

As per the specifications shared it seems like dot-env is working only for development and test environment but not for production.

Secondly, you need to set the environment variables ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_KEY so that they are available in Rails.

You can do this in the terminal:

```
export ACCESS_KEY_ID=<your access key id>
export AWS_KEY=<your secret key>
```

Add those to your .bashrc or .bash_profile so they persist next time you start a new shell or use something like dotenv to make them specific to your project.

Another way could be setting their values in secrets.yml or .env file

Comment: when you say "so that they are available in Rails" what do you mean by that? if I go on console and type ENV["ACCESS_KEY_ID"] I get what i am looking for. And I do have the .env file

Comment: ENV["ACCESS_KEY_ID"] in console should give you the value which you set in .env file

Comment: Also have you made the changes in application.rb so that while loading the application it should require your .env file??

Comment: when you say "made the changes in application.rb" when I start rails everything works fine. it is only when I try to precompile the assets....